# throwing exception in let run clause is thrown when value is not null

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a null safe operator block as follows, and if the value is null, I want to throw an exception. However, I'm experiencing that whether or not the value is null, the exception is thrown. The call to firebase returns `Void`, so does it get interpreted as null?

```
Firebase.auth.currentUser?.let { firebaseUser ->
    Firebase.firestore.collection("mycollection")
                    .document("mycollectionid")
                    .collection("mychild")
                    .document("mychildid")
                    .set(data, SetOptions.merge())
                    .await()
} ?: run {
    throw Exception("currentUser is null")
}
```

How can I make sure that I throw the error only if the let block doesn't execute?

Comment: What is returned from `doWork()`? Isn't it maybe `null`?

Comment: It returns `Void`. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` returns whatever the lambda returns. `await()` probably doesn't return anything, which is why the `run` is executed.

You probably want to replace `let` with `also`. This works the same as `let` except it returns whatever object it is called on instead of the lambda result.

See also [Function selection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#function-selection)